# Making a custom static value like CGFloat.infinity in Swift

Tags: swift

As may most of you know we have a value like `CGFloat.infinity` which if we print it, it prints `inf` which is a little wired! because CGFloat has no alphabet or string but numbers!

However I want to build my own custom value like `CGFloat.infinity` called `CGFloat.cool` I want get print result of `cool` like we can get `inf` for `CGFloat.infinity`, so how can i define a static value for CGFloat which in prints it prints `cool` but in the same time it is just a CGFloat and not a String.

```
extension CGFloat {
    static var cool: CGFloat {
        get {
            return 0
        }
    }
}


func test() {
    
    let value1: CGFloat = CGFloat.infinity
    let value2: CGFloat = CGFloat.cool
    
    print(value1)
    print(value2)

}
```

results:

> inf

> 0.0

Comment: `0` is already a number so it cannot be `.cool`.

Comment: I think you are confusing the **value** of the CGFloat, with its representation as a String - they are not the same thing. `CGFloat.infinity` is not a String with value "inf", it's a number, whose value depends on the system (for example something like `1.79769e+308`) represented the same way as any other number of its type. However when this number is converted to String (e.g. on `print`), instead of printing that long unreadable number, it prints `"Inf"`. That's it. There's no magic there.

Comment: @jjquirckart: I am not confusing, you better check your information about `1.79769e+308` that is not about it you are mixing 2 deferent topics, we are not talking about max value or anything like that, since you commented some value like `1.79769e+308` for `CGFloat.infinity` then probebly you should inform yourself about infinity as well in general, as soon as you give a number or value to infinity it shows a wrong understanding, by the way what you call it value or "representation", I want be shown or "representation" when I use print function.

Comment: @jjquirckart's comment is completely correct that 64-bit infinity is roughly 1.79769e+308 if you interpret the bits as if they were a "normal" floating point number. That bit pattern is just reserved as "infinity." It has very little to do with the mathematical meaning of "infinity."

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr:** Unfortunately, on a type you don't own (like `CGFloat`), you can't (and in this specific case, even if you could, you couldn't distinguish between `0` and `CGFloat.cool`).

Types in Swift use the [`CustomStringConvertible` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible) to define a conversion from a value to a `String`, and when a type conforms to this protocol, `print` and similar debug tools defer to the implementation of that protocol to get a string value to display.

In this case:

1. [`CGFloat.description`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/ee856f110177289af602c4040a996507f7d1b3ce/Sources/Foundation/CGFloat.swift#L467) defers to `Float`/`Double.description` to produce a result (depending on the platform)
2. [`Double.description`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/ab6faa9c00891882d26e003922f38dcde8ed35b2/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPointTypes.swift.gyb#L97) handles known `Double` values specifically:

   - For `.nan`, it produces the result `"nan"` directly; for all other values, it defers to a function called [`_float64ToString`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/6d255658ca0120e6cd9a910e6712c047f672ecb0/stdlib/public/core/Runtime.swift#L357)
   - `_float64ToString` defers to a function called [`swift_float64ToString`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a9fe9716da8b3398d4fbf14d62d2656dd0c36bd7/stdlib/public/stubs/Stubs.cpp#L197)
   - `swift_float64ToString` defers to a function called [`swift_dtoa_optimal_double`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/f8c608a3fd3ecd365d962a78e1e6f2ef1ae08cb3/stdlib/public/runtime/SwiftDtoa.cpp#L762), which itself defers to [`swift_dtoa_optimal_binary64_p`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/f8c608a3fd3ecd365d962a78e1e6f2ef1ae08cb3/stdlib/public/runtime/SwiftDtoa.cpp#L772)
   - Now in the meat and potatoes, `swift_dtoa_optional_binary64_p` [checks for, and handles, infinity specifically](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/f8c608a3fd3ecd365d962a78e1e6f2ef1ae08cb3/stdlib/public/runtime/SwiftDtoa.cpp#L804), and this is what [returns `"inf"`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/f8c608a3fd3ecd365d962a78e1e6f2ef1ae08cb3/stdlib/public/runtime/SwiftDtoa.cpp#L282)

The key to this, however, is that it's `Double.description` that determines what you see when you `print` a value, and its implementation of the protocol eventually converts the bit pattern of `Double.infinity` into `"inf"`. There are two difficulties with `Double.cool`:

1. `Double.description` has an implementation that you can't inject behavior into. It is in charge of controlling its string representation, and you can't meaningfully change it;
2. Even if you could, `CGFloat.cool` has the *exact* same representation as `0`, and it wouldn't be possible to tell them apart — `print(0)` and `print(Double.cool)` are *exactly* the same on the calling side, so you can't override the values separately

So in all, there isn't anything you can do in this case specifically. For your own types, you can implement `CustomStringConvertible` yourself for `print` to use (and decide on whatever behavior you want there), but in this case, you'll need to find an alternative solution.

Comment: In my question I have to return a value in my get and I use zero the plan was not to return zero, the goal is returning `cool`, like this: `get { return "cool"}` but it is not possible because i should return CGFloat and not String. So the value of zero in return was not and is not important, since you and another person in comments focusing on zero, I guess you might misunderstood my question, or may I could not explain it, the return can be 1 or 100 or 54, I have to return CGFloat, but the goal is not to return a CGFloat like zero, the goal is returning `cool` when I print `CGFloat.cool`

Comment: @ioscoder To be clear: _because_ you have to return a `CGFloat` value and cannot return a `String`, and _because_ you cannot change how `CGFloat` prints, you cannot get `"cool"` to print out when you print `CGFloat.cool`, regardless of the value. The `0` in my answer was just matching your original question — it doesn't matter if the value is `0` or `1` or `54` or `100`: because the value is _equal_ to `0` or `1` or `54` or `100`, it will be printed exactly the same way.

Comment: @ioscoder The real question is: why do you need `cool` to be printed out when you `print(CGFloat.cool)`? Is it for your own use in debugging, or is it something else? Some more detail in the question about why you need this will help; perhaps there is an alternative solution that we can help come up with.

Comment: I really thankful for your help, but the way that `CGFloat.infinity` works is interesting for me, I like to learn and make custom value for learning like `CGFloat.cool`, all the things you mentioned could be right no issue there, but still I cannot solve and get needed code or answer for my wished goal in question.

Comment: I am just a passer by on this question, but I appreciate reading this great insight to the internals of the language.

Answer (score 4):

`CGFloat.infinity` is not a String. It is one of the values that CGFloat can hold.

```
print(CGFloat.infinity.bitPattern)
// 9218868437227405312
```

In binary, it is the following bit pattern:
0111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

This is in the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) format, with one sign bit, 11 exponent bits, and 52 mantissa bits.

You'll note that this is not actually "infinity" in any mathematical way. According to the normal interpretation of floating point bit patterns, this would be 2^1024 (or approximately [1.79769e+308](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2%5E1024), as @jjquirckart correctly noted). But, according to the IEEE format, this bit pattern is special and interpreted as "infinity."

There are many other special bit patterns in IEEE floating point. Most useful for your question would be the [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) (not-a-number) values, which are all bit patterns that have all ones in the exponent (like infinity), but have at least one set bit in the mantissa. For example, the bit pattern:

```
0111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
                                                               ^
print(CGFloat(bitPattern: 9218868437227405313))
// nan
print(CGFloat(bitPattern: 9218868437227405313).floatingPointClass)
// signalingNaN
```

To your question, what you've specifically asked for is impossible as Itai Ferber described. You cannot change CGFloat's `description` (which is what is used by `print`).

You can create a non-signaling NaN to hold a special "not a number" value if you like:

```
extension CGFloat {
    static var cool: CGFloat { CGFloat(bitPattern: 0x7FF80000636F6F6C) }
}
```

But note that NaN does not behave like numbers (they are, after all, *not* a number). For example, a NaN is neither less than, greater than, or equal to any other value, including another NaN (even if their bit patterns are the same).

```
print(CGFloat.cool == CGFloat.cool)
// false
```

The only way you can check that it's "your" value is to check the bit pattern:

```
print(CGFloat.cool.bitPattern == CGFloat.cool.bitPattern)
// true
```

You can use this to transmit "special" values through the system, however, and this is supported. You can use the 51 low bits of the mantissa to encode whatever you like (as long as you don't use all zeros). The high bit of the mantissa encodes whether it's a "quiet" (non-signaling) NaN.

If you wanted to create some new "number-like" thing that had all the values of CGFloat and also another "cool" value, and printed the way you wanted it too, you'd have to make your own number type. It couldn't be CGFloat.

(This is slapped together and not well tested, and it assumes this is a 64-bit platform, and it's a ton of code to do it, but this is how you would.)

```
// A CGFloat that has one special NaN called .cool
struct ExtendedNumber {

    // This is a bit pattern for a non-signaling NaN value.
    // It is not meant to be interpreted as an integer.
    // The low order bits of the mantissa are the UTF-8 encoding of "cool"
    private static var coolBitPattern: UInt = 0x7FF8_0000_636F6F6C
    static var cool: ExtendedNumber { ExtendedNumber(CGFloat(bitPattern: coolBitPattern)) }

    var value: CGFloat

    init(_ value: CGFloat) { self.value = value }
    var bitPattern: UInt { value.bitPattern }

    // This allows `.cool == .cool` to be true
    func isEqual(to other: ExtendedNumber) -> Bool {
        (self.bitPattern, other.bitPattern) == (Self.coolBitPattern, Self.coolBitPattern)
        || value.isEqual(to: other.value)
    }
}

// This allows `print(ExtendedNumber.cool)` to print "cool"
extension ExtendedNumber: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        self == .cool ? "cool" : value.description
    }
}
```

And this is all the boilerplate required for ExtendedNumber to conform to BinaryFloatingPoint:

```
extension ExtendedNumber: BinaryFloatingPoint {
    mutating func round(_ rule: FloatingPointRoundingRule) { value.round(rule) }
    static func /= (lhs: inout ExtendedNumber, rhs: ExtendedNumber) { lhs.value /= rhs.value }
    init(sign: FloatingPointSign, exponentBitPattern: CGFloat.RawExponent, significandBitPattern: CGFloat.RawSignificand) {
        value = CGFloat(sign: sign, exponentBitPattern: exponentBitPattern, significandBitPattern: significandBitPattern)
    }
    var exponentBitPattern: CGFloat.RawExponent { value.exponentBitPattern }
    var significandBitPattern: CGFloat.RawSignificand { value.significandBitPattern }
    init(sign: FloatingPointSign, exponent: CGFloat.Exponent, significand: ExtendedNumber) {
        value = CGFloat(sign: sign, exponent: exponent, significand: significand.value)
    }
    var exponent: CGFloat.Exponent { value.exponent }
    func distance(to other: ExtendedNumber) -> CGFloat.Stride { value.distance(to: other.value) }
    func advanced(by n: CGFloat.Stride) -> ExtendedNumber { Self(value.advanced(by: n)) }
    init(integerLiteral value: CGFloat.IntegerLiteralType) { self.value = CGFloat(integerLiteral: value) }
    init(floatLiteral value: CGFloat.FloatLiteralType) { self.value = CGFloat(floatLiteral: value) }
    typealias RawSignificand = CGFloat.RawSignificand
    typealias RawExponent = CGFloat.RawExponent
    typealias FloatLiteralType = CGFloat.FloatLiteralType
    typealias Exponent = CGFloat.Exponent
    typealias Stride = CGFloat.Stride
    static func *= (lhs: inout ExtendedNumber, rhs: ExtendedNumber) { lhs.value *= rhs.value }
    static func - (lhs: ExtendedNumber, rhs: ExtendedNumber) -> ExtendedNumber { Self(lhs.value - rhs.value) }
    typealias IntegerLiteralType = CGFloat.IntegerLiteralType
    static var exponentBitCount: Int { CGFloat.exponentBitCount }
    static var significandBitCount: Int { CGFloat.significandBitCount }
    var binade: ExtendedNumber { Self(value.binade) }
    var significandWidth: Int { value.significandWidth }
    static var nan: ExtendedNumber { Self(CGFloat.nan) }
    static var signalingNaN: ExtendedNumber { Self(CGFloat.signalingNaN) }
    static var infinity: ExtendedNumber { Self(CGFloat.infinity) }
    static var greatestFiniteMagnitude: ExtendedNumber { Self(CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude) }
    static var pi: ExtendedNumber { Self(CGFloat.pi) }
    var ulp: ExtendedNumber { Self(value.ulp) }
    static var leastNormalMagnitude: ExtendedNumber { Self(CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude) }
    static var leastNonzeroMagnitude: ExtendedNumber { Self(CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude) }
    var sign: FloatingPointSign { value.sign }
    var significand: ExtendedNumber { Self(value.significand) }
    static func * (lhs: ExtendedNumber, rhs: ExtendedNumber) -> ExtendedNumber { Self(lhs.value * rhs.value) }
    static func / (lhs: ExtendedNumber, rhs: ExtendedNumber) -> ExtendedNumber { Self(lhs.value / rhs.value) }
    mutating func formRemainder(dividingBy other: ExtendedNumber) { value.formRemainder(dividingBy: other.value) }
    mutating func formTruncatingRemainder(dividingBy other: ExtendedNumber) { value.formTruncatingRemainder(dividingBy: other.value) }
    mutating func formSquareRoot() { value.formSquareRoot() }
    mutating func addProduct(_ lhs: ExtendedNumber, _ rhs: ExtendedNumber) { value.addProduct(lhs.value, rhs.value) }
    var nextUp: ExtendedNumber { Self(value.nextUp) }
    func isLess(than other: ExtendedNumber) -> Bool { value.isLess(than: other.value) }
    func isLessThanOrEqualTo(_ other: ExtendedNumber) -> Bool { value.isLessThanOrEqualTo(other.value) }
    var isNormal: Bool { value.isNormal }
    var isFinite: Bool { value.isFinite }
    var isZero: Bool { value.isZero }
    var isSubnormal: Bool { value.isSubnormal }
    var isInfinite: Bool { value.isInfinite }
    var isNaN: Bool { value.isNaN }
    var isSignalingNaN: Bool { value.isSignalingNaN }
    var isCanonical: Bool { value.isCanonical }
    init?<T>(exactly source: T) where T : BinaryInteger {
        guard let value = CGFloat(exactly: source) else { return nil }
        self.value = value
    }
    var magnitude: ExtendedNumber { Self(value.magnitude) }
    static func + (lhs: ExtendedNumber, rhs: ExtendedNumber) -> ExtendedNumber { Self(lhs.value + rhs.value) }
}
```

But if you do all of that, then, as requested:

```
let value1 = ExtendedNumber.infinity
let value2 = ExtendedNumber.cool

print(value1)  // inf
print(value2)  // cool
```